# Version conflict when using buildout.plonetest 4.3.x

Tags: plone, buildout

I wrote a small module that extends https://raw.github.com/collective/buildout.plonetest/master/test-4.2.x.cfg. If I change the version from 4.2 to 4.3 it throws the error when running `bin/buildout`:

```
...
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section test.
  Initializing section test.
  Installing recipe zc.recipe.testrunner.
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: zc.recipe.egg 2.0.0
```

I suppose that the error is produced because some packages listed in the `buildout.plonetest` have conflicting versions and that is a bug in the 4.3 version set. I'm right or I'm making a mistake in the `buildout.cfg` file?

The buildout that I'm using is:

```
[buildout]
extends =
    https://raw.github.com/collective/buildout.plonetest/master/test-4.2.x.cfg
package-name = conaride.theme
package-extras = [test]

[instance]
eggs +=
    Pillow

[test]
defaults = ['-s', '${buildout:package-name}', '--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bug in the 4.3 version set; you need to fix the version conflict. Try any or all of the following approaches to this very-common problem:

(1) Remove the already-downloaded version and re-run Buildout e.g.:

```
$ rm -rf eggs/zc.recipe.egg\*
$ bin/buildout
```

(2) Remove the installed config and re-run Buildout e.g.:

```
$ rm .installed.cfg
$ bin/buildout
```

(3) Specify the version you want to use in your local config e.g.

```
[versions]
zc.recipe.egg = 2.0.0
```

Comment: The approach (1) solves the problem. It installs the version 1.3.2 of the zc.recipe.egg. I installed eggs globally in the ~/.buildout/eggs, so I removed zc.recipe.egg versions 1.2.2, 1.3.2 and 2.0.0. That confuse me is my previous experience with Bundler (that I use in Ruby projects). With Bundler I can install several gems globally and only versions indicated (or required by the indicated) in the Gemfile are used. That means that Buildout doesn't allow having several versions of an egg installed globally?

Comment: Python itself does not support multiple versions of a library in a single environment… use virtualenv and install different versions in different environments if you want to work around that missing functionality.